# Is it good to rewrite your old db migration for unused column in your table?

Tags: php, laravel, migration, database-migration

Removing unused code is a good practice. But is DB migrations script file an exception in this practice?

I have to maintain a Laravel application and I'm in the process of cleaning up unused code and I found out I have lots migrations scripts. My migration includes adding and dropping table columns.

Anyone who have encountered the same situation? Thanks!

Comment: are you going to need the DB migration script again?

Comment: @Dagon Not necessary. I want my migration to be cleaned up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the migration does not affect anything on the database, then it is fine to remove them.

But, if they affect, even a little part like adding/removing (same or different) columns, changing types ... then look up current data carefully if your in **PRODUCTION**; otherwise, refactoring before production is good.

Comment: I would agree with you the idea of "Not updating migrations scripts and just adding new migrations for the update especially in production".